# Elasticsearch multi index query with geo bounding box query

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch enable you to query multiple indices on fields that exists or not on  those indices.

But when querying on multiple indices with the geo_bounding_box elastic throws exception if the queried fields not exists in all requested indices.

it seems that elastic check if the required fields are mapped as geo-point.

Is there a way to achieve this query without editing mapping and adding all geo_fileds in all indecies?

Comment: Perhaps only include the indices in your search that contain a geo field.

Comment: The thing is that all the indices contains geo fields but not with the same name. e.g index A.x_location, index B.y_location and the query using bool query with should on both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`indices` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html) in a `bool/should` arrangement like below. This way you don't run the risk of querying an index with the wrong field name:

```
POST /indexA,indexB/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "indices": {
            "indices": [
              "indexA"
            ],
            "query": {
              "geo_bounding_box": {
                "x_location": {...}              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "indices": {
            "indices": [
              "indexB"
            ],
            "query": {
              "geo_bounding_box": {
                "y_location": {...}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
it seems to work , but now I have strange results, using should returns all documents from both indices,  change it to must returns the correct documents, Why there is a difference of bool query on multi-index query?